# Find then hide drawn shape in image?

Tags: c#, image, c#-4.0

This may seem like a strange question, but I have a set of pictures I want to use as a fading screen saver, and I want each picture to have an accompanying quote, but each quote will be in a different place, relative to the picture.

Rather than coding a `Rectangle` for the area of each image, it would be easier just to draw a rectangle in the image, and have it drawn in there.

Now, the drawn shape would be a stark, uniform coloured border (lime green, for instance) because the colour doesn't appear in the pictures, and it would be on a solid coloured background, like black for instance.

My question is: If I draw a lime green rectangle on each image, how could I then, using C#, find that rectangle in the image, get the dimensions of it, and replace the lime green with the background colour, so in the end product, it'd look like the shape was never there to begin with?

I have not tried anything, I have no code to show, because it's an idea I had and though I'm sure it must be possible, I don't even know what to start searching for.

I hope this is possible, if it isn't, then I'll just draw a rectangle for each one, but that's a last resort. :)

Comment: Absolutely nothing. It's just an idea right now, because I wouldn't even know what to start googling.

Comment: You should probably try to make it yourself, and then post a question about a specific problem. We can't be expected to write the program for you. ;)

Comment: @annonymously I'm not expecting you to write it for me, just point me in the right direction ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you thought about using either the [emgucv](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) or [aforge](http://www.aforgenet.com/) libraries? They are able to detect shapes in images quite easily. Though they don't detect edges perfectly, if all you want to detect is a rectangle, either one should work well.

Here are two tutorials on shape detection for [emgu cv](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Shape_%28Triangle,_Rectangle,_Circle,_Line%29_Detection_in_CSharp) and [aforge](http://www.aforgenet.com/articles/shape_checker/). Once you have the shape detected, then you can easily cut it out for the background. Say, for example, that you used the aforge Detection of quadrilaterals (in the link), then you could easily get the rectangles position and size by the calling of `blobs[i].Rectangle;` and create a rectangle with same size and position with picture background color.

If you need more clarification please feel free to comment. Nice idea!

Comment: This looks extremely promising :) But, something I can't tell after having read through them is, I see they detect shapes, but they detect *all* shapes in my image. How can I limit it to say, a shape of just one colour? Because I don't know exactly what shapes my image are going to contain, nor what size my search-for rectangle will be, so I can't code that in. Any ideas? Is there a point, or even a page, that I missed?

Comment: You said @Spiritfyre "Now, the drawn shape would be a stark, uniform coloured border (lime green, for instance) because the color doesn't appear in the pictures," well if the color doesn't appear in the picture, you could just find out if the blob area contains lime green. For instance, loop through the pixels in the blob until you find the color (if it's all one color it should take just one loop) and if you find it, break and have that as the blob to remove. If you want to be really sure that it is all one color, than loop through till you have say 10 pixels of the same color.

Comment: Of course. Sorry, I was just doing a little more research into the matter. Looks like Both will work perfectly, though `AForge` looks simpler to use. Thankyou @SuperPrograman :)